# Raid0 performance degradation?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, performance, raid-0

Not sure if this belongs here or on SuperUser, feel free to move as appropriate.

I've noticed the performance on my RAID0 setup seems to have degraded over the past months.  The throughput is fine, but I think the random access time has increased or something.

In use I generally see about 1-5mb/sec when loading stuff in Visual Studio and other apps and it doesn't seem like the CPU is bottlenecking as the CPU utilization is pretty low.  I don't recall what Access Time used to be, but HD Tune is reporting 12.6ms  Read throughput is showing as averaging about 125MB/sec so it should be great for sequential reads.  Defrag daily and it shows fragmentation levels low, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Additional info, Windows 7 x64, Intel raid controller on mobo, WD Black 500GB (I think 32mb cache) x2.

Answer (score 1):

Possible candidates:

- Full NTFS. With space available <10%, NTFS performane suffers, but mostly (not only) for writes
- Internal remapping of sectors of the HDDs. Look at the SMART data.
- File system damage

Answer (score 0):

How old disks? Usually performance will start to suffer unexplainable when disks start to develop errors due to age, heat or just plain bad luck...

Answer (score 0):

Run a chkdsk on the hard disks, any file system free space discrepancies will kill drive performance, chkdsk will fix any free space issues. You can also set chkdsk to do a sector check, it takes much longer but may be worth your time. I prefer to do it from the Windows recovery environment command prompt.