# Why does HDTune report better performing drives 2 months after installing them?

Tags: hard-drive, speed, benchmarking

OK, so this is really weird. I ran HDTune on a newly set-up home-built computer and got the following readings from my drives in mid-November.

1. SSD    154 MB/s
2. RAID1  87
3. RAID0  198 (software installs)
4. RAID0  98  Swap drive

Today, in January, I run HDTune (same version) and get these results, in MB/s:

1. SSD    186
2. RAID1  98
3. RAID0  241
4. RAID0  98   (Swap drive)

Here are more details that HDTune reports on the SSD drive:
HD Tune: OCZ-VERTEX Benchmark

> Blockquote
>
> Transfer Rate Minimum : 135.4 MB/sec
>
> Transfer Rate Maximum : 219.4 MB/sec
>
> Transfer Rate Average : 185.7 MB/sec
>
> Access Time           : 0.1 ms
>
> Burst Rate            : 187.3 MB/sec
>
> CPU Usage             : -1.0%

To get to my question: Why are my hard drives improving in performance?  Most of my logical drives are in some form of RAID, except for the SSD.  Will this performance ever deteriorate? Note, none of my drives are a hybrid drive that uses some form of SSD to enhance the write/reads on actual platters.

Comment: Somebody had the reverse issue: http://superuser.com/questions/132648/raid0-performance-degradation

Answer (score 1):

[Windows SuperFetch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista_I/O_technologies#SuperFetch), which monitors your usage of your computer and intelligently loads data from your drives at the right time to optimize performance, may be responsible for the performance increase.

**Edit:** Though I'm not sure about how SuperFetch may affect a synthetic benchmark, this is still a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: A recent windows update had new drivers installed for your system. A chipset graphics driver may also have influence on HDD speed (DMA issues).

But maybe you just forgot a seemingly innocent change to your system...